# read variable value from bash executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a script:

x.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo nir
```

config.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(/home/nir/x.sh)
```

script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#execute config.sh and read x into y
print(y)
```

terminal:

```
$ ] ./x.sh
nir
$ ] . ./config.sh
$ ] echo $x
nir
$ ] ./script.py
nir
```

I want to use `config.sh` in a python script to execute it and then read the value in `x`. Not sure how to do it.

Comment: `echo nir` will not echo `nir` variable. I think you may have wanted to use `echo $nir`

Comment: To make it clear: In your example, you want to receive the string _nir_ inside your Python program?

Comment: added example to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `config.sh` is not showing output, you need another command for showing the value of x. Any shell variable set in a subprocess is lost when the subprocess is finished, so you can not use two calls to `subprocess`.
The same problem is valid for `config.sh`: the variables are lost when the script is finished. You need to `source` the file with a `.` for the variable to be remembered in the subprocess environment. Before finishing the subcommand, you must `echo` the value.
All steps together:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

cmd = '''
. /home/nir/config.sh
echo "$x"
'''

# returns output as byte string
returned_output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True)

# using decode() function to convert byte string to string
y=returned_output.decode("utf-8")
print(y)
```

Comment: work great! one question - how can I make the path of config.sh relative to the location of `script.py`? (which is the script you actual wrote)

Comment: Try `. ./config.sh` (first dot for source, second for relative to current dir).

Comment: found it `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),....`